# Angular - event binding

Tags: angular, event-handling

Here is a Bootstrap panel. If user clicks icon, hidden parts becomes unhidden, but what I need is to unhidden only that part that was clicked.

```
   @Component({
      template: `
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" *ngFor="let fizz of fizzes">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <i class="glyphicon {{ fizz.iconClass }}"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                {{ fizz.heading }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down clickable" (click)="onClick()"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" [hidden]="!clicked">
            {{ fizz.content }}
          </div>
        </div>
      `
    })

    export class FizzComponent {
      fizzes: object[];
      clicked = false;

      onClick(event: any) {
        this.clicked = !this.clicked;
      }
    }
```

I could achieve it by defining every action on its own, but how do I do it in a more generic way?

Tried to pass `$event`, like so:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down clickable" (click)="onClick($event)"></i>
```

And

```
  onClick(event: any) {
    event.target.clicked = !event.target.clicked;
  }
```

But without any luck..

Comment: It's kind of difficult to understand what you're asking. Could you create a Plunker to demonstrate? Or perhaps add an image to show the behaviour?

Comment: is click event firing did you checked with console log

Comment: @Jonnysa - yes it does. Definitely checked that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a generic, reusable solution, just write a directive to do what you ask. Then, you just need to declare it in the proper module and add it on the elements.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appHideOnClick]'
})
export class HideOnClickDirective {



    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
        // toggle hidden on clicked
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }

    @HostBinding('hidden') isHidden = false; // initialize without hidden attribute 

    constructor() {}
}
```

then in your markup:

```
<div class="panel-body" appHideOnClick >
```

Remember that not every element in Angular has the `hidden` attribute styling attached to it. You may need to either change the directive to apply `display: none` to the element style, or stick a global rule for the `hidden` attribute in the `styles.css/styles.scss`:

```
[hidden] {
    display: none; // may need to be !important
}
```